# Amazon RDS python boto

Tags: python-2.7, boto3, rds

Currently I am working on a Python script to create an RDS and a snapshot and copy the snapshot to another region.

While I am copying my snap to another region, it is creating in same region.

Here is my coding to copy.

```
con = boto3.client('rds','us-west-2')
               print "connected to us-west"
               ec.copy_db_snapshot(SourceDBSnapshotIdentifier='chris-snap',TargetDBSnapshotIdentifier= 'chris-copy-snap',SourceRegion='us-east-1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Things to try:**

Explicitly stating the region in your `boto3.client()` call:

```
con = boto3.client('rds', region_name='us-west-2')
```

Where did "ec" come from? You set the RDS service to "con" so it should be con.

Per Boto3 documentation:

> If the source snapshot is in a different AWS Region than the copy, specify a valid DB snapshot ARN.

Substitute `'chris-snap'` with the ARN.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code.

```
 ec.copy_db_snapshot(SourceDBSnapshotIdentifier='chris-snap',TargetDBSnapshotIdentifier= 'chris-copy-snap',SourceRegion='us-east-1'
```

1. The second connection is not declared or using the incorrect name
2. When copying a snapshot across region, you cannot use the snapshot identifier, you must use the snapshot ARN.

This link includes a  method used Cloud Watch Events to trigger a lambda function when an automated snapshot is created. The snapshot is immediately copied across region.

https://geektopia.tech/post.php?blogpost=Automating_The_Cross_Region_Copy_Of_RDS_Snapshots